# Redirecting to another site by masking url

Tags: .htaccess, masking

I want to redirect all the users who enters www.siteA.com/folder1  to www.siteB.com/folder. But user should see www.siteA.com/folder1 in address bas even after redirection to www.siteB.com.

I do not know how to do it with .htaccess  Can somebody please help me how to mask the url. I really need your help.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to put such kind of configuration directly into your Apache configuration and not use `.htaccess`. In general .htaccess files hurt the performance and should only be used if you have no access to the server configuration and/or need them because of the software you are installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "Force the substitution URL to be internally sent as a proxy request" via the `P` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^folder1(.*) http://www.siteB.com/folder$1 [P]
```

There are some other examples in the [documentation of the RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

<s>If this does not work (e.g. no access to the server configuration and the proxy module is disabled) you are probably best of using a Proxy script like [PHProxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpr0xi).</s>

On a second look I think PHProxy is not really what you need. Maybe give this one a try: http://code.google.com/p/php-proxy/ - The installation instructions look pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the samething with Rewrite Engine On but its not hiding the url, its getting redirected. i dont know why

Comment: It might be the case that rewrite rules in `.htaccess` files are not allowed to use the `Proxy` flag. Have you tried putting in the Apache configuration as proposed by my comment?

Comment: No. I haven't tried. Actually i am using a hosted server. Is it possible to access Apache Configuration file on 3rd Party hosted server? Plz help me

Comment: In this case you can not use the builtin Proxy module of Apache. You are probalby best off using a Proxy script: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpr0xi/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am novice in server management. I have uploaded it to my server, but i am not getting how to use it. Will you please guide me in this.

Comment: You should maybe start another question. On a second look I think PHProxy is not really what you need. Maybe give this one a try: http://code.google.com/p/php-proxy/ - The installation instructions look pretty simple.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton ton ton!. I have achieved it. Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

You want to use proxying . On Apache, [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) should do what you are looking for.

Bear in mind that your server will eat up twice the amount of bandwidth. Once to get the data from the source server and again to send it to the client.